# Is it possible to create an interface without using dynamic dispatch?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

### Background

I'm writing the firmware for an embedded project with a couple of 'choices'. For example, the device uses a humidity sensor, but it supports multiple different humidity sensors.

To implement this nicely, I have written an (abstract) base class as an interface to represent the sensors:

```
class HumiditySensor {
public:
    virtual void readSample() = 0;
    virtual double getHumidity() const = 0;
    virtual double getTemperature() const = 0;
};
```

Now, different specific sensors can inherit from this base class and implement the pure virtual methods.

```
class SHTHumiditySensor : public HumiditySensor {
private:
    SHTSensor &sht;
public:
    explicit SHTHumiditySensor(SHTSensor *sht);
    void readSample() override;
    double getHumidity() const override;
    double getTemperature() const override;
};

class DHTHumiditySensor : public HumiditySensor {
private:
    DHT &dht;
public:
    explicit DHTHumiditySensor(DHT *dht);
    void readSample() override;
    double getHumidity() const override;
    double getTemperature() const override;
};
```

In other parts of my code, I can just 'ask for' a (pointer to) `HumiditySensor` and not care about what kind of sensor it is, or how it is implemented, because they expose the same common interface. E.g. in a class that needs a humidity sensor:

```
class Humidistat {
private:
    HumiditySensor &hs;
public:
    Humidistat(HumiditySensor *hs);
}
```

Based on a config constant, in `main.cpp` I'll either instantiate either of the two sensors, and pass a pointer to it in the instantiation of a `Humidistat`.

I have a few more cases like this in my project (multiple possible UIs for different displays, etc).

### Problem/question

This is all fine and well, but as far as I understand this all takes quite a bit of precious flash/RAM on my microcontroller because this uses dynamic dispatch / run-time polymorphism.

However, which of the two derived classes I'm going to use is in principle fixed and known at compile-time. It would therefore be nice to avoid the overhead of run-time polymorphism, but is this possible?

Thus, if I understand correctly, what I want is static (or compile-time) polymorphism. I have found that this can be accomplished with the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP), but it looks quite convoluted/hacky and I'm wondering if that's really the simplest way to achieve what I want.

Comment: You could just `#define TheHumiditySensor DHTHumiditySensor` and if it changes, change it.

Comment: CRTP is really the only way to get compile time polymorphism.

Comment: It should not use much more extra FLASH, and the virtual tables will be quite small so not much extra RAM either. Using templates can lead to much more code "bloat" which could use much more FLASH, and possibly much more RAM as well. Using static polymorphism will be more CPU effective though, since it's all done at compile-time.

Comment: And if it's possible to get stats about FLASH usage (should be very easy) and RAM usage (might be harder) then use that first to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Other than that what Some programmer dude says, I think you don't even need CRTP or runtime polymorphism, if you just use templates for `Humidistat` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3WvEEzzYK). If you only use one humidity sensor per project, you will only instantiate one `Humidistat` class and therefore, you will neither have runtime nor memory overhead.

Comment: @user253751 I'm trying to avoid preprocessor magic like that because it's not type-safe, but in this case it might actually solve more problems than it causes.

Comment: You said your choice is "in principle fixed and known at run-time". Did you mean to say "... known at compile time"?

Comment: @MikevanDyke Interesting approach! I'll look into it.

Comment: @Useless Yes, that was an error, thanks. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one class, so there is no polymorphism by definition. You don't need inheritance, interfaces, CRTP, or any such hacks.

```
class SHTHumiditySensor /* no ': public HumiditySensor' needed */ {
private:
    SHTSensor &sht;
public:
    explicit SHTHumiditySensor(SHTSensor *sht);
    void readSample() /* no virtual, no override */;
    double getHumidity() const /* no virtual, no override */;
    double getTemperature() const /* no virtual, no override */;
};

using HumiditySensor = SHTHumiditySensor;
```

Comment: Well, in my current implementation I definitely had run-time polymorphism (since I use `virtual` functions), but you might be right that I don't need it.

Comment: Also, this way I don't get to define the interface explicitly, but neither do I with the template approach...

Comment: The design you present here has the disadvantage that `using` will determine the used implementation "globally", so we won't be able to add another `Humidistat` that uses a different `HumititySensor` to the same translation unit (say, run one with SHT and one with DHT in parallel). This is why I prefer the solution of @eeroika, which corresponds to the suggestion by @MikevanDyke given in the comment to the OP.

Comment: @HelpingHand This is precisely what OP says is **not** needed/wanted.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I have overlooked that different OP is only considering alternative use of implementations. Rereading OP, it becomes clear.

Comment: The system will let me improve my rating only next time the answer is edited.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the cost of runtime polymorphism, then you must rely on compile time polymorphism instead. The tool for compile time polymorphism is templates.

Yes, templates can be harder to use; compile timeness limits what can be done. CRTP that you mention is a useful technique in some use cases, but I don't see a need for it in the shown example.

In the most simple case, you could use templates such as this:

```
template <class Sensor>
class HumiditySensor {
   Sensor &sht;
   // ...
};

// If needed:
// using SHTHumiditySensor = HumiditySensor<SHTSensor>;
// using DHTHumiditySensor = HumiditySensor<DHT>;

template <class Sensor>
class Humidistat {
    HumiditySensor<Sensor> &hs;
    // ...
}
```

To specify how to define a `Sensor` class usable in such template, you simply specify a *concept* of a class that has certain members. This is largely the way the STL is defined. Previously, such concepts have been written documentations, but in C++20 there is now a way to define them programmatically - that's largely optional but can have some benefits.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is similar to what @MikevanDyke suggested in a comment. I don't think I can template the HumiditySensor class like that though, since its implementation depends on the sub-type. That's fine though

Comment: @Compizfox Then treat `HumiditySensor` as a concept instead.

Comment: How would I "define the interface" in this case, though? With inheritance I would do that with pure virtual methods in the abstract base class, but with templates I don't see a way to do this. Is this where concepts come in?

Comment: @Compizfox The concepts are the interfaces.

Comment: Another quick question. I have made my `Humidistat` class a class template. However, there are other classes that require a (pointer to a) `Humidistat` class, that now don't work because I have to explicitly instantiate the class template. What do I do with those classes? Templatize them as well? And then what about classes that require those classes? That quickly means I have to templatize my entire application.

Comment: @Compizfox `Templatize them as well?` Yes. All the way to the top. That is the cost of compile time polymorphism. You can use type-erasure to cut off that chain of templatisation at the cost of runtime overhead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236092/discussion-between-compizfox-and-eerorika).